# Junit 5 analog of a codeception dataProvider?

Tags: junit5

Codeception framework have tools such as [`dataProvider`or `examples`](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#examples)
provides array of the data for concrete test case.

Has Junit-5 something like this?

I read documentation and found the `dynamic tests` but it's is not what I need. And `Parametrized classes` is a part of a Junit-4 not a Junit 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such thing exists yet but the prerequisite for creating such an extension  is under development.

[JUnit 5's extension model](http://blog.codefx.org/design/architecture/junit-5-extension-model/) allows third party libraries to interact with JUnit via *extension points* and one that allows the generation of test cases based on input data is going to exist in the next milestone (M4). It is likely that it will be the *test template extension point* proposed in [PR #642](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/pull/642).

Comment: Parameterized tests are indeed the main theme of M4. The API is probably going to look like in these examples: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/6f20c50e3fee0c8ad58148b85c8b391f181a22a5/junit-jupiter-params/src/test/java/org/junit/jupiter/params/ParamsApiPlayground.java.